# how to exchange data with my android application and a remote server

Tags: android, database

i have to set up a database on a remote server (with users login information and aso other data that are going to be retrieved). That database is going to be used with an android app i'm creating too. Now I am really undecided about the choice of tools to use. I usually use a mysql db for database and volley library in the android app(with php scripts in the middle), but i wonder if volley is the best to use,may i use another type of db? or isn't there another way easier to do such apps.
If anyone can advise me, it will be really helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to use the jdbc class to query MySQL database directly from your Java code ( Google jdbc in Java) ... Or better still use  HTTP class to query a API endpoint( you will need to create a backend code with php or nodejs, E.t.c for this) to receive  json response.

Comment: ok..so either I go with Google jdbc directly or I stay with HTTP requests.

Comment: Yes... I will advise you create a script (php or others) in the middle to perform your queries and connect API to your Android app

Comment: well! but you know, i was thinking also about a secure exchange between the app and the db, how can that be achived

Comment: It is bad to open your database directly to Scenario like what you are trying to do.. It's not advisable